# site map page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

how to create site map page (like http://www.google.com/sitemap.html or http://www.microsoft.com/presspass/sitemap.mspx) in asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a web.sitemap file as indicated by krusaint [ [Build a SiteMap](http://aspalliance.com/695_CodeSnip_Building_a_Site_Map_with_ASPNET_20) ] and then you can programmatically enumerate the sitemap nodes [ [MSDN - How to: Programmatically Enumerate Site-Map Nodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178424(v=VS.85).aspx)  ] to construct a table similar to the page that google uses.
http://www.google.com/sitemap.html

Google's sitemap.html page is nothing more than a table with several un-ordered lists of links.  It should be pretty easy to replicate by viewing the source of their page.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_navigation.asp is one of the basic resources you can start with. You can also refer http://aspalliance.com/695_CodeSnip_Building_a_Site_Map_with_ASPNET_20 for this. Do you have any specific issue while doing this?

Comment: Perfectly said by Robert Williams. http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2004/09/13/site_nav_aspnet20.html is another example of how to implement.